# Why is my disc always blank after a reportedly successful burn?

Tags: burning, brasero, k3b

After the tools report a successful burn, the disk appears to be blank.
I tried the burn with brasero and k3b multiple times.

Any suggestions to actually burn the CD?

Comment: Do you run Ubuntu 32bit or 64bit ubuntu? K3b seems to have a bug for 64bit ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/k3b/+bug/978621

Comment: it could be due to `cdrkit` [the back-end], you should try `cdrtools` [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/ubuntu/cdrtools) instead

Answer (score 0):

I had once that problem:
- disc ain't closing properly
- disc is low quality
- lens from burner is worn out

If the disk is really burning (you can see the tracks) check other it with different driver.

Answer (score 0):

Use root privileges(may not be the best option, but this seems to be the only solution right now)
Open terminal and type `sudo k3b`.

I was on 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04. Opening the application this way solved the issue for me.

Comment: running `k3b` with root privileges is **not a good idea™**.

Comment: According to this bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/k3b/+bug/978621 , this might be the only option we have untill its fixed